# C++ pointers and string vectors

Tags: c++, vector, c-strings, strchr

```
//Add words from the file to the vector
while (inputFile >> word) {
    listWords.push_back(word);
    wordCount +=1;  //Count the words
}

for (int i = 0; i < listWords.size(); i++) {
    char *p;
    p = strchr(listWords.at(i), 'c');
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        cout << "null";
    }
}
```

The code I have here adds a rather large text file of words to what I have declared as a string `vector listWords`.  I would like to use `strchr` and various other Cstring functions to get rid of individual words with certain letters and characters.  I'm coming across an error when trying to do so saying "No matching function call to `strchr`."  I have already included the libraries `<vector> <string> <cstring> <fstream>`.  Pretty sure my error lies between the pointers.

`char *strchr(const char *str, int ch)`

Any tips to what I should do here to make strchr work?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Important things: what is the type of `listWords`.

Comment: listWords is of type string and it is a vector.

Comment: Does `listWords.at(i)` returns a `string` or a `char*`? If listWords is a `std::string vector`... you may need to try something like `listWords.at(i).c_str()` which will return a const char*

Comment: If `listWords` is a vector of `std::string` you should use [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Answer (score 1):

Better

```
for (int i = 0; i < listWords.size(); i++) {
    const auto p = listWords.at(i).find('c');
    if ( p != std::string::npos ) {
        cout << "null";
    }
}
```

Worse

```
for (int i = 0; i < listWords.size(); i++) {
    const char *p = strchr(listWords.at(i).c_str(), 'c');
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        cout << "null";
    }
}
```